# How can I extend this sql query to delete all rows which match the ID of its results?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning about more complex queries. Take the following sql, which looks through a table to find possible duplicates, where basically x = y, or y = x. ie it's the same entry, but the id's are in opposing columns.

```
SELECT 
    a.match_id as a_match_id, 
    b.match_id as b_match_id 
FROM 
    matches a, 
    matches b 
WHERE 
    a.primary_linked_id=b.secondary_linked_id 
AND 
    a.secondary_linked_id=b.primary_linked_id 
AND 
    a.date = b.date';
```

What I want to do, is then from the list of b_match_id's returned, is delete  all those results.

I only know how to do this with php, where I would then loop through all those results and construct another sql query for each row. This is slow.

How would I basically add-on something like this:

```
DELETE FROM matches WHERE match_id=b_match_id
```

.. so that it all is done with 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE b
FROM
    matches a, 
    matches b 
WHERE 
    a.primary_linked_id=b.secondary_linked_id 
AND 
    a.secondary_linked_id=b.primary_linked_id 
AND 
    a.date = b.date
```

???

Comment: Seems very direct and simple. A little too simple for my taste :D And surprisingly it worked. But why ``DELETE b``? That threw me off, and even phpmyadmin saw it was a problem. I thought it must be a typo but of course, it doesn't work without it. I don't know what it is with my brain but I find sql queries confusing as hell.

Comment: @willdanceforfun: When you join tables in a `DELETE` statement, MySQL needs to be told which side of the join(s) it should be deleting from... of course, one could delete both sides with `DELETE a, b FROM ...` if you wanted (but that isn't what you're after in this case).  See [DELETE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html) for more information.

Comment: "A little too simple for my taste" What does that even mean?

Comment: That I overcomplicate things :|